# Get values from an HTML table row and pass them to a modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Im trying to make a webpage that has a table and the user must be able to click on a filtered row or a non-filtered row and a modal should pop up displaying more info about the selected row.

Here is the main code (table included)

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
<h1>Issues Repository</h1>
<div class="container-1">
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
<input type="search" id="search" ng-model="searchBox" placeholder="Buscar..." />
</div>
<div>


</div>
<div id="divBuscador" ng-controller="issues">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="tableList"  cellspacing="0" border=1>

    <tr>
      <th>OpCo</th>
      <th>Tecnologia</th>
      <th>Version</th>
      <th>Titulo del Issue</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>

        <tr class='clickable-row' data-target="#contentModal" style="cursor:pointer" id="issueList"  ng-repeat="document in documents | filter:searchBox" ng-click="openModal(documents)">
        <td id="opCo_Val">{{ document.opCo}}</td>
        <td id="tec_Val">{{ document.Tecnology }}</td>
  <td >{{ document.Version }}</td>
  <td >{{ document.Issue }}</td>
  <td >{{ document.Status }}</td>
        </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

This is the function linked to the on-click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
                $('#contentModal').modal('show');
        });
        });
```

This is the controller:

```
app.controller('issues',  ['$scope', function($scope, $modal){
$scope.documents = fileX.records;

}]);
```

How can i do to pass variables to the modal, like {{ document.Version }} or {{ document.Issue }}

Please explain everything, Im new to angular.

Comment: @PankajParkar please explain yourself...I do not know how to apply ng-click

Comment: have you try to use library like ui-bootstrap it has amazing modal who explain how pass data.

Answer (score 0):

as i understood, you need to get data from clicked row?

This code below will get you that.

```
 $('#example tr').click(function(){
          $(this).find("td").each(function(){
          alert($(this).html());
        });
    });
```

I've printed values in alert box and it works perfectly. If you want to store each value to array just push it with this lines of code:

```
    $scope.tableRowValues = [];
    $scope.tableRowValues.push($(this).html());
```

inside of .each method

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I´ve found the solution by myself, but thanks for the answer, anyway i will need some explanation about storing values on the array, would you help me with that?

Comment: with command push from above, you are storing each value of object one by one in array

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the solution of this issue by deleting the above jQuery and adding this to the controller:

```
  $scope.openModal=function (index, ob)
  {
     $scope.id=index;
  $scope.selected_issue=ob;
  }
```

And also I´ve set ng-click and data-target to the row:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" id="issueList" ng-repeat="issues in issue | filter:searchBox" ng-click="openModal($index, issues)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contentModal">
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!